# Issues when adding LinearLayout to RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, google-calendar-api

I'm implementing a fragment to view a schedule. Each of these events are parsed from the Google Calendar API format. For ease of use (people will be using this app whom are not part of our organization so they won't have read/write access to the calendar), I'm trying to bake a google calendar viewer into this app (you'll notice it's stylized in a very similar manner).

Here's an example of the structure of an event:
[image: event structure]

An event is comprised of two textviews (title and description) spaced 5dp apart, which are contained in a vertically oriented LinearLayout. A RelativeLayout is the root container in this layout.

**My issue:**
These events are spaced in the proper location by using their `margin:top` values. `margin:left` should be 55dp to avoid overlapping with the time markers on the left hand side. I mention this because spacing is key to having this implementation work correctly, so I need to retain this at all costs. This seems possible using `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, but please correct me if I'm mistaken.

However, before I get there, I can't even get an event to display. My event info is parsed correctly, calculations are performed correctly (verified by log statments), it seems the LinearLayout is being created. However, when I view the schedule I can only see the time markers and the gridlines. No events.

Below is the code I'm using to build the LinearLayout and attach it to my root RelativeLayout:

```
    private void addShow(String title, String description, int startTime, int endTime) {

    /* Build the LinearLayout to function as the container for this show. Since the size of the container is to represent
    the length of the show, its height must be proportional (1dp = 1 minute) to the length. Determine length by finding the difference
    between the start and end times. */
    int difference = endTime - startTime;

    /* Define the margins of this show. All shows must not overlap the displayed times, which are 50dp in width.
    Add 5 more (to the right and left) to see the schedule lines for clarity. Push the show down to align with the appropriate time marker using the top margin value set to the
    difference (in minutes) between midnight and the start of the show. */
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dpToPixels(difference));
    rlLayoutParams.setMargins(dpToPixels(55), dpToPixels(startTime), dpToPixels(5), 0); // l, t, r, b

    /* Build LinearLayout and apply parameters */
    LinearLayout eventLL = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    eventLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    eventLL.setPadding(dpToPixels(5), dpToPixels(5), dpToPixels(5), dpToPixels(5));
    eventLL.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.orange_rounded_event);
    eventLL.setLayoutParams(rlLayoutParams);

    /* Add title of event to LinearLayout */
    TextView titleTV = new TextView(getActivity());
    titleTV.setText(title);
    eventLL.addView(titleTV);

    /* Determine length of event to see if we have room to attach a description (if one was passed) */
    int length = endTime - startTime;
    if (length >= 60 && description != null) {
        TextView descriptionTV = new TextView(getActivity());
        descriptionTV.setText(description);
        eventLL.addView(descriptionTV);
    }

    /* Add this view to the schedule UI */
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.schedule_container_relativelayout);
    rl.addView(eventLL);
}
```

And just in case it might be screwing something up, here's the dp to px method I'm using that I found here on StackOverflow:

```
/**
 * Converts dp values to an appropriate amount of pixels based on screen density of this device.
 * @param dp value of dp to convert
 * @return equivalent pixel count
 */
private int dpToPixels(int dp) {
    Resources r = getActivity().getResources();
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

While I've got a decent amount of experience in Android dev, dynamic layouts are something I've barely touched. I didn't want to attach the entire Fragment, just because it's pretty big, but I certainly can if more context is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who may come across this question from a search engine, I found a fix.

For some reason, it worked when I defined margins using the public methods of `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` members directly.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rrLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dpToPixels(difference));
rrLayoutParams.leftMargin = dpToPixels(55);
rrLayoutParams.topMargin = dpToPixels(startTime);
rrLayoutParams.rightMargin = dpToPixels(5);
```

And I had to pass the parameters into `addView()`

```
rl.addView(eventLL, rrLayoutParams);
```